# Reducing a Python Script

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could shorten this program?

```
_=map(ord,raw_input());_=[10if y==88else 0if y==45else 58-_[x-1]if y==47else y-48for x,y in enumerate(_)];t=0;exec('t+=sum(_[:2+(_[0]+_[1]>=10)]);_=_[2-(_[0]==10):];'*10);print t
```

[Run it online](https://tio.run/##Lc3RCoMgGAXg@z2Fd9lK0mjLFe45BJGf2IwFy8KM5dO3im7O4Xw3Zwz@M9h8XUH0zYgH905d84POjrPHcVyDUIx2LQpCcG6@k0HnKm7HunECaiFMn1oeGkjB28GhJQ2os8jYuTeu8QZDrC9e0Nos5oUjn4hp7jGoKk@2pDoBxfRTMBrr/RpUTg4XO1W6jq5b16PrrEd@XWWZPYgknGfkLqXk7A8)

I'd like to write a bowling calculator. I'm fairly proficient in python so I chose that language.

The trick is that the input string is made up of frames not split by white-space and the spares, strikes, and misses are marked by `/`, `X`, and `-` respectively. (note that there are no `0` in the code, `-` is used instead)

Here is an example line `X7/9-X-88/-6XXX81`, this line would have a score of `167`.

As you can see, most of my characters are spent on mapping these special characters to their actual bowl scores. I do this by taking their `ord` values and then replacing the `X` and `-` with `10` and `0` respectively. I then find the `/` rolls and set their value as ten minus the previous roll.

After this, I calculate the final game score by looping over 10 frames (the size of a line of bowling), chunking the line array based on if the  frame was a strike spare or normal roll, and then reducing the array going forward.

I feel like this is the best way to perform this challenge as a golf challenge, but I'm not sure if I'm reducing it enough.

Comment: @user202729 The TIO link, as well as the use of print strongly suggests it is not.

Comment: @user202729 Just changed it, thanks!

Comment: To be clear a spare (`/`) can never come after a gutter (`-`)?  Your current code doesn't seem to handle this.

Comment: Oh and welcome to the site by the way!

Comment: I'm getting a score of 176 for your example. Could you maybe write out the bowling scoring rules to make sure we're all on the same page about how they are calculated?

Comment: Here are the scores I have after each roll: `X 10;
7 24;
/ 30;
9 48;
- 48;
X 58;
- 58;
8 74;
8 82;
/ 84;
- 84;
6 90;
X 100;
X 120;
X 150;
8 174;
1 176`.

Comment: @user202729 I can use any language.

Comment: @xnor I added the wikipedia with the rules, it's easier than writing them out.

Comment: @user202729 yes it is guaranteed

Comment: @user202729 Feel free! But my office decided that only "real" languages are allowed to compete for the free lunch (python, perl, ruby, javascript, etc). I'm guessing it will be up for debate depending on our submissions (it's a small office).

Comment: I suppose the last edit is only for the bonus section? Because the question is Python only? ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80049/discussion-between-swiper-cccvi-and-user202729).

Comment: OK, I was missing that if the game goes into extra frames, those frames are not scored. Are we guaranteed that the game as listed lasts exactly ten frames and those extra rolls are listed exactly if the the game goes into those extra frames?

Comment: A naive translation to J. Just for fun. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEEDRfU9hNOlocIBBbQGp55ikCyVqYl3oQnYVr45s389/lhIHf2pJX9ZbTxrP1H7lJgOS2e0PXW8dwyQ/6Ta9AJo0eN0sZZZH0qsAY31jlj@DLswyjjUnIVScKwkXhDJVoblfH@9FKoV75ZDRWoUdM1v6Aw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: This could make for an interesting challenge, assuming it hasn't been done already.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/score-a-game-of-bowling).

Comment: Yeah, [it's been done already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/160259/58974)

Answer (score 5):

## 1.

The portion `2+(_[0]+_[1]>=10)` could be rewritten as `2+(_[0]+_[1]>9)` to save two bytes. In a similar vein `2-(_[0]==10)` can be rewritten as `2-(_[0]>9)`, since `10` is the only possible value greater than `9`.

```python
a=map(ord,raw_input());a=[10if y==88else 0if y==45else 58-a[x-1]if y==47else y-48for x,y in enumerate(a)]
t=0;exec('t+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10);print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3RCoMgGIbh812FZ@lKyqhlhbsOQWT8bMaEZWHG6upbi04@eJ@Tb1zDe3D5toHoYcSDfyUevg/rxjlgQloQimW2Q6sQnJvPZNBZRXlUySmohTJ9anXoSgveDR4tyYqsQ8bNvfEQDAaiL0FkrVnME0chFtPcY1BNHu@b6RgU0/ea6P8xqJweukOj2@jKMtKO3rqAwrbJKq2ppJyn9Cal5OwH)

(I also renamed `_` to `a`, because even though it's code-golf we don't have to make it unreadable)

## 2.

You can also use a dictionary instead of conditionals to saves some bytes.

```python
a=raw_input();a=[{y:ord(y)-48,'X':10,'-':0,'/':58-ord(a[x-1])}[y]for x,y in enumerate(a)]
t=0;exec('t+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10);print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3dCsIgAEbvewrv1DaZjn6cYs8hiISU0S7mhjmaRM9uWzfn4nwcvimn5xjaUpyK7n3twzQnhKVT5pPFGO8oY3LgNdRQMFpDAsXKBoojJ9vqzEKYxV@T7WOMYKkz6APwYR58dMkjh@0uKSr94m8Ipkq95mGNRFutpLZyhtlLh@326ExL/nYVwkq4ZxTLKfYhgVSKPjcd0YTzhpy01pz9AA)

## 3.

Don't `enumerate`.  `enumerate` tends to be too long for it's own good.  Here you want to get the last character, which can better be acheived with a `zip`.

```python
a=raw_input();a=[{y:ord(y)-48,'X':10,'-':0,'/':58-ord(x)}[y]for x,y in zip('-'+a,a)]
t=0;exec('t+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10);print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3dCsIgAEbvewrv1FTmRj/OYc8hiITUIi9yYo5m0bOvrZtzcb4DXyz5PoRmnp1K7nX2IY4Z4c4p8ylySFdUMNsJCjWUNaeQQbmwgnIv2LpO@GuKvQ0JTLQAH8DbR7RUxFGH7SYr3vVTf0EwE/UcH8gZ2ZCF3BJnantqsV3PnGnY3y5C2g5ua467mHzIIM@zPlYt00yIih201qL@AQ)

---

If you combine this with @user202729's two tips you get 149 bytes.

```python
a=raw_input();a=[[10,0,58-ord(x),ord(y)-48]['X-/'.find(y)]for x,y in zip('-'+a,a)]
t=0;exec't+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10;print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1LDsIgAEXRuatgBliw0PihJbgOEkIM0TYykBKksXXz2Dp5NzmTF5f8HENTilPJfW4@xCkjLJ0yhjPCyEnQMT3QjMmWBdOjsAZqWsPD4MMmdhgTmMkCfABfHxGksHLEYbvLisl@7u8wV@o9vZAzXVOty2zlDLfXFtvtyZmG/nWFzkq450zG5EMGuRR9qVuqqRA1PWutBf8B)

---

Here's another version that is also 149 bytes:

```python
a=raw_input();a=[['-123456789X'.find(y),58-ord(x)][y=='/']for x,y in zip('-'+a,a)]
t=0;exec't+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10;print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc3BDoIgHIDxe0/h7Q8pKZaKOnoONsYaS10cQka4pJc36/IdfpfPxfCYbbltmnv9vhnrloBwr7mUQGh5vlR1w1oBp8nYAUWcVYzMfkArVjJyDjmoafbJmsXE2ORjHAICqc40VofAi35cxzuElL@WJ9KyK9O9hUq1pOraYvU7aVmSv@7QqR6OtOidNzYkYdtEk7dEEMZyUgshGP0C)

Comment: Wow, fantastic response! And here I thought I was being clever with my use of enumerate to save some time. Thanks!

Comment: @Swiper-CCCVI Glad that helps.  I would suggest waiting a little while before accepting an answer, there are definitely some people that are much better at python golfing than I am, and this question has only been viewed 18 times so far.

Comment: Sure can do, I wish it was possible to accept multiple!

Answer (score 3):

## Shorten the conditional using `str.find`

Compare:

```
Mine:        [10,0,58-_[x-1],y-48]['X-/'.find(chr(y))]
Mine (char): [10,0,58-ord(a[x-1]),ord(y)-48]['X-/'.find(y)]
WW's:        {y:ord(y)-48,'X':10,'-':0,'/':58-ord(a[x-1])}[y]
Original:    10if y==88else 0if y==45else 58-_[x-1]if y==47else y-48
```

Comment: @CatWizard ... That's because you use characters and I use character codes...

Comment: Yeah, looks like I confused myself, if you implement this with characters rather than codes you save 2 bytes.  [Try yours](https://tio.run/##Hc1LDoMgAATQfU/BDqhQwfSDEnoOEkIa0mLKQjQUUz091W4mk7eYmdb8HmNTilPJfR8hTnNGWDplDGeEkYugY3ohZxbKLSZ7XzE9C2ugpjU89SHuYvsxgYWsIETg4zz45LJHDttDVkz6xT8RzJX6zMM21TXVlsxWznB7b7Hd/5xp6F836KyER86wnFKIGeRS9K1uqaZC1PSqtRb8Bw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## 146 bytes

Based on Cat Wizard's ["another version"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/168451/6).

Basically I include `/` into the string so `find` returns `0` (falsy value), then use `or` to replace that `0` with the desired result.

```python
a=raw_input();a=[('/-123456789X'.find(y)or 59-ord(x))-1for x,y in zip('-'+a,a)]
t=0;exec't+=sum(a[:2+(a[0]+a[1]>9)]);a=a[2-(a[0]>9):];'*10;print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1LDsIgFAD3noIdIMUWtP/Uc5AQYl5sG1lICdLYevla3Uwysxm/xsfk5LZBF@B9s87PkdAWOk1wyoU8X/KirGqFT6N1PVnpFFBe8yn0ZKGUi3H3JVmRdehjPcEcM0iAmkPssnZYhjuOrHvNTwK6kWxnZhhoYa41Nb8NaMn/dQ@NafFRZK0P1kUUt02Vac0Vr6qUF0qpSnwB)

Explanation: `x or y` == `x if x else y`. So:

```python
   '/-123456789X'.find(y)or 59-ord(x)
== '/-123456789X'.find(y) if '/-123456789X'.find(y) else 59-ord(x)
== '/-123456789X'.find(y) if '/-123456789X'.find(y) != 0 else 59-ord(x)
== '/-123456789X'.find(y) if y != '/' else 59-ord(x)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the .find(y)or section is working? I'm having a hard time understanding how this is checking if the character is a spare or not.

Comment: @Swiper-CCCVI If the character is a spare `'/-123456789X'.find(y)` will be zero.  This short circuits the `or`, because `0` is the same as false, so it returns the second part of the `or` which is the `59-ord(x)`.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now. Thanks! And very nifty.

Answer (score 2):

## Remove `()` around parameter of `exec`

`exec` is a command, not a function. This saves 2 bytes.

Comment: Nice catch! I did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you need to use `raw_input()` and not replace it with `input()` and wrap the input string in quotes e.g. "X7/9-X-88/-6XXX81"? That would save 4.